# Getting audio buffer data

Tags: c#, .net, audio, naudio

I am using naudio and I was curious how I could get the audio buffer data.

Is there a way to obtain the audio buffer data from a Wave file read from WaveFileReader? I would like to eventually save it to a file.

I assumed that to do so was

byte[] buffer = new byte[wave.Length];
wave.Read(buffer, 0, (int)wave.Length);

However, is wave.length the length of the audio data buffer, or is it the length in respect to duration? If not duration, how can I get the duration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`wave.Length` is the number of bytes of audio data. The `TotalTime` property of a `WaveStream` will attempt to convert this into a TimeSpan.